# How to define MonadUnliftIO instance for a newtype with a phantom type-variable?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, newtype, deriving

Related question - [Is it safe to derive MonadThrow, MonadCatch, MonadBaseControl, MonadUnliftIO, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863771/is-it-safe-to-derive-monadthrow-monadcatch-monadbasecontrol-monadunliftio-et) - where I had enabled, both - `DeriveAnyClass` and `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` 
to get the code to compile, but didn't bother looking at the ominous warnings. Now, that I am running my refactored code, it's throwing a runtime error:

```
No instance nor default method for class operation >>=
```

So, I removed `DeriveAnyClass` and kept ONLY `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` and have the following compile error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeFamilies, AllowAmbiguousTypes, RankNTypes, StandaloneDeriving, UndecidableInstances #-}

newtype AuthM (fs :: [FeatureFlag]) auth m a =
  AuthM (ReaderT (Auth auth) m a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader (Auth auth), MonadIO, MonadThrow, MonadCatch, MonadMask, MonadUnliftIO)


--     • Couldn't match representation of type ‘m (Control.Monad.IO.Unlift.UnliftIO
--                                                   (AuthM fs auth m))’
--                                with that of ‘m (Control.Monad.IO.Unlift.UnliftIO
--                                                   (ReaderT (Auth auth) m))’
--         arising from the coercion of the method ‘Control.Monad.IO.Unlift.askUnliftIO’
--           from type ‘ReaderT
--                        (Auth auth)
--                        m
--                        (Control.Monad.IO.Unlift.UnliftIO (ReaderT (Auth auth) m))’
--             to type ‘AuthM
--                        fs auth m (Control.Monad.IO.Unlift.UnliftIO (AuthM fs auth m))’
--       NB: We cannot know what roles the parameters to ‘m’ have;
--         we must assume that the role is nominal
--     • When deriving the instance for (MonadUnliftIO (AuthM fs auth m))
--    |
-- 82 |   deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader (Auth auth), MonadIO, MonadThrow, MonadCatch, MonadMask, MonadUnliftIO)
--    |                                                                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Note:** I realise that the first error about `>>=` has got nothing to do with the error about `MonadUnliftIO`. I have confirmed that there are no warnings about a missing `>>=`, when `DeriveAnyClass` is turned off.

I guess I need to write the instance for `MonadUnliftIO` myself, because the compiler probably cannot figure this out in the presence of a `newtype` AND a phantom type-variable. However, I just can't figure out how to define the [`askUnliftIO`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/unliftio-core-0.1.1.0/Control-Monad-IO-Unlift.html#v:askUnliftIO) for my type, given above.

#### Attempt 1 at minimal code snippet

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Try13 where

import Control.Monad.Reader
import UnliftIO
import Control.Monad.Catch

data Auth = Auth

newtype AuhM m a = AuthM (ReaderT Auth m a)
  deriving(Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Auth, MonadIO, MonadThrow, MonadCatch, MonadMask, MonadUnliftIO)

--     • Couldn't match representation of type ‘m (UnliftIO (AuhM m))’
--                                with that of ‘m (UnliftIO (ReaderT Auth m))’
--         arising from the coercion of the method ‘askUnliftIO’
--           from type ‘ReaderT Auth m (UnliftIO (ReaderT Auth m))’
--             to type ‘AuhM m (UnliftIO (AuhM m))’
--       NB: We cannot know what roles the parameters to ‘m’ have;
--         we must assume that the role is nominal
--     • When deriving the instance for (MonadUnliftIO (AuhM m))
--    |
-- 12 |   deriving(Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Auth, MonadIO, MonadThrow, MonadCatch, MonadMask, MonadUnliftIO)
--    |                                                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--
```

Comment: Could you provide the definitions of `Auth` and `FeatureFlag`, or simplify this code to the minimal part that reproduces this issue? Right now it's impossible to easily reproduce the error you're getting, and I'm sure you could cut out a few irrelevant parts.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I have added a minimal code snippet to the question. As a first step, I was able to get the error with just the newtype (i.e. without phantom-type).

Comment: Not related to your question, but I think you newtype might be misspelled `AuhM` vs `AuthM`?

Comment: @lehins yes, good catch :)

Answer (score 8):

Plan:

- How to implement `MonadUnliftIO` by hand.
- How to newtype-derive `MonadUnliftIO`.

## Implement explicitly

```hs
newtype AuthM m a = AuthM { unAuthM :: ReaderT Auth m a }
  deriving ...

instance MonadUnliftIO m => MonadUnliftIO (AuthM m) where
  askUnliftIO = AuthM (fmap (\(UnliftIO run) -> UnliftIO (run . unAuthM)) askUnliftIO)
  withRunInIO go = AuthM (withRunInIO (\k -> go (k . unAuthM)))
```

There is nothing magical about this; here's how you can derive the definition of `askUnliftIO`. We want to wrap the existing instance of `MonadUnliftIO` for `ReaderT Auth m`. Using that instance, we have:

```
askUnliftIO :: ReaderT Auth m (UnliftIO (ReaderT Auth m))
```

And we are looking for

```
_ :: AuthM m (UnliftIO (AuthM m))
```

In other words, we want to replace the two occurrences of `ReaderT Auth` with `AuthM`. The outer one is easy:

```
AuthM askUnliftIO :: AuthM m (UnliftIO (ReaderT Auth m))
```

To get at the inner one, we can use `fmap`, and then the problem becomes to find the right function `UnliftIO (ReaderT Auth m) -> UnliftIO (AuthM m)`.

```
fmap _ (AuthM askUnliftIO) :: AuthM m (UnliftIO (AuthM m))

-- provided --

_ :: UnliftIO (ReaderT Auth m) -> UnliftIO (AuthM m)
```

We're now looking for a function, and the library doesn't provide any functions on `UnliftIO`, so the only way to start is a lambda with pattern-matching, and since the function result is `UnliftIO`, we can also start with a constructor:

```
(\(UnliftIO run) -> UnliftIO (_ :: forall a. AuthM m a -> IO a) :: UnliftIO (AuthM m))
  :: UnliftIO (ReaderT Auth m) -> UnliftIO (AuthM m)

-- where (run :: forall a. ReaderT Auth m a -> IO a)
```

Here we see that `run` and the hole only differ in their arguments. We can transform a function's argument by function composition, we fill the hole with `run . _`, containing a new hole:

```
(\(UnliftIO run) -> UnliftIO (run . (_ :: AuthM m a -> ReaderT Auth m a)
                                :: forall a. AuthM m a -> IO a
                             )
) :: UnliftIO (ReaderT Auth m) -> UnliftIO (AuthM m)
```

That hole is finally filled with the destructor `\(AuthM u) -> u`, aka. `unAuthM`. Put all the pieces together:

```
fmap (\(UnliftIO run) -> UnliftIO (run . unAuthM)) (AuthM askUnliftIO)
```

Note that `fmap f (AuthM u) = AuthM (fmap f u)` (by definition of `fmap` for `AuthM`), which is how you get the version at the top. Whether or not to do that bit of rewriting is mostly a matter of taste.

Most of these steps can be carried out with the help of GHC's *typed holes*. There's some loose ends at the beginning when you try to find the right shape for the expression, but there might also be a way to use typed holes to help with that part of the exploration as well.

- See also [Implement With Types, Not Your Brain!](https://reasonablypolymorphic.com/blog/typeholes/)

Note that none of this requires any knowledge about the purpose of `askUnliftIO` nor `AuthM`. It's 100% mindless wrapping/unwrapping between `AuthM` and `ReaderT`, i.e., 100% boilerplate that could be automated, which is the topic of this next section.

## Derive

Technical explanation of why deriving doesn't Just Work. The extension `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` tries to coerce `ReaderT Auth m (UnliftIO (ReaderT Auth m))` to `AuthM m (UnliftIO (AuthM m))` (in the case of `askUnliftIO`). However, this is not possible if `m` depends on its argument nominally.

- For more details, see also this blogpost, which also gives the solution summarized below: https://ryanglscott.github.io/2018/03/04/how-quantifiedconstraints-can-let-us-put-join-back-in-monad/

We need a "representational role" constraint, which we can encode as follows thanks to `QuantifiedConstraints` which appeared in GHC 8.6.

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints, RankNTypes, KindSignatures #-}
-- Note: GHC >= 8.6

import Data.Coerce
import Data.Kind (Constraint)

type Representational m
  = (forall a b. Coercible a b => Coercible (m a) (m b) :: Constraint)
  -- ^ QuantifiedConstraints + RankNTypes               ^ KindSignatures
```

Thus annotate the derived instance with that constraint:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, StandaloneDeriving #-}

deriving instance (MonadUnliftIO m, Representational m) => MonadUnliftIO (AuthM m)
```

---

Full snippet:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, StandaloneDeriving, QuantifiedConstraints, KindSignatures, RankNTypes #-}

module Try13 where

import Control.Monad.Reader
import UnliftIO
import Control.Monad.Catch
import Data.Coerce
import Data.Kind (Constraint)

data Auth = Auth

newtype AuthM m a = AuthM { unAuthM :: ReaderT Auth m a }
  deriving(Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Auth, MonadIO, MonadThrow, MonadCatch, MonadMask)

type Representational m = (forall a b. Coercible a b => Coercible (m a) (m b) :: Constraint)

deriving instance (MonadUnliftIO m, Representational m) => MonadUnliftIO (AuthM m)

-- instance MonadUnliftIO m => MonadUnliftIO (AuthM m) where
--   askUnliftIO = AuthM (fmap (\(UnliftIO run) -> UnliftIO (run . unAuthM)) askUnliftIO)
--   withRunInIO go = AuthM (withRunInIO (\k -> go (k . unAuthM)))
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this insightful answer. The second part is some new level of type-fu that I haven't seen till now. Let me play around with this with my original and come back with the results!

Comment: In which GHC version was `QuantifiedConstraints` introduced? i'm getting an `Unsupported extension` error.

Comment: It appeared in GHC 8.6 https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#quantified-constraints

Answer (score 4):

As of version 0.2.0.0 of `unliftio-core`, the `askUnliftIO` function has been moved out of the typeclass, which makes it possible to `newtype`-derive this instance again!

```hs
data FeatureFlag
data Auth auth

newtype AuthM (fs :: [FeatureFlag]) auth m a = AuthM
  { unAuthM :: Auth auth -> m a
  }
  deriving newtype
    ( Functor
    , Applicative
    , Monad
    , MonadReader (Auth auth)
    , MonadIO
    , MonadThrow
    , MonadCatch
    , MonadMask
    , MonadUnliftIO
    )
```

cf https://github.com/fpco/unliftio/issues/55